# Kolourpaint: set colort default to red

Tags: kde, configure, kolourpaint

I'm using kolourpaint on Ubuntu 20.04. The most common usecase for me is open an temporarily created picture and add some mark on it, thus I need default color set to red.

I found that some settings are stored in `~/.config/kolourpaintrc` (text settings, tool settings, etc). I tried `kolourpaint --help`, `man kolourpaint`, and search through the Internet, but couldn't find any useful information about how to config kolourpaint with `kolourpaintrc` file. Does anyone know how to do this? Or any other way to set default color to red?